# Implementing functions that include name and symbol

Tags: symbolic-math, sage, symbolic-references

I need to define in Sage some functions with **attributes** that define

- the *name* of the function
- its mathematical/physical *symbol*
- the *definition* of the function
- (and those in combination)

and **methods** that return

- those *attributes in LaTeX* format

both **symbolic and with parameters** input and then also

- the *result of the function* on those parameters

An example is something like

```
>>> somefunction.name
\text{some function}
>>> somefunction.symbol
\mathrm{SF}
>>> somefunction.definition
\mathrm{SF} = 3x + y
>>> somefunction(4, 5)
17
>>> somefunction(4, 5).symbol
\mathrm{SF}\left(4, 5\right)
>>> anotherfunction.name
\text{another function}
>>> anotherfunction.symbol
\mathrm{AF}
>>> anotherfunction.definition
\mathrm{AF} = 2z
>>> anotherfunction('SF')
2(3x + y)
```

I suppose the way of implementing it is by defining a new class that inherits from the `function` Class. And perhaps the method names should have `_latex` appended.

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance,

Chris

Answer (score 1):

You definitely don't want to just use `function` if you are planning something more interesting.  See if [the tips for implementing new symbolic functions](https://trac.sagemath.org/wiki/symbolics/functions#Tipsforimplementingnewfunctions) fits your needs (though this may be overkill).  Yes, you definitely want something with a latex attribute/method.

Comment: Thanks, I'm giving it a go :-)